# Terracotta make-boot-jar.sh run fail

Tags: java, caching, distributed, terracotta

When `exec make-boot-jar.sh` I get the following error:

```
2017-06-17 02:12:42,209 INFO - Successfully loaded base configuration from file at '/home/hadoop/terracotta-3.7.7/tc-config.xml'.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9216
    at com.tc.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:2015)
    at com.tc.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:469)
    at com.tc.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
```

Has anyone ever been in this situation?

Comment: env: terracotta-3.7.7 ; centos6.8 ;jdk1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the magic Terracotta was weaving inside a JVM and the fact that DSO is discontinued, I am pretty sure the error is because Terracotta 3.7.7 is not compatible with Java 8.